# How can we use where condition in array_merge result in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, array-merge

Here when I use my code like this am getting error `Function name must be a string in`,please have a look.

```
public function get_date_wise_agent_report($start_date,$end_date,$agent = NULL,$abc = NULL)
{
    $results1=$this->db->get('datas')->result();
    $results2=$this->db->get('abc_datas')->result();
    $data=array_merge($results1,$results2);
    $this->db->where_in('Date(date) >=',$start_date);
    $this->db->where_in('Date(date) <=', $end_date);

    return $data();
}
```

I had used `array_merge` to combine two results and from that I need to get get results between the two dates hope you can help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be corrected as below.

```
public function get_date_wise_agent_report($start_date, $end_date, $agent = NULL, $abc = NULL)
{

    $this->db->where("DATE(date) BETWEEN '{$start_date}' AND '{$end_date}'")
    $query = $this->db->get('datas');
    $results1 = $query->result_array();

    $this->db->where("DATE(date) BETWEEN '{$start_date}' AND '{$end_date}'")
    $query = $this->db->get('abc_datas');
    $results2 = $query->result_array();

   //Here you need to use $query->result_array() instead of $query->result() because result() returns a object.
   //Go to following link to learn more about result

   //Here I assumed both `datas` and `abc_datas` tables are having `date` column.

    $data = array_merge($results1,$results2);

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: thanks my problem was actually i had used bracket after $data anyway i needs this in future

Comment: i have a doubt whether can we use where condition for the array_merge result